# Choose project to run in multi-project workspace

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am looking at iOS the demo project for AppoDeal in xcode:
[https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-ios-demo][1]

It has 3 projects in the workspace.
How do I choose which project I want to run in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the three schemes relating to targets in the respective projects. Choose the scheme you want and that should run the project/target you want.

Comment: Thanks!  I spent a while looking for that.